# how to copy text file in text box using c#?

Tags: c#, textbox, text-files

i like to copy the whole textfile into multiline textbox ,how can i do these?

Answer (score 8):

```
 textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ReadAllLines` method to read the file as an array of strings, and put that in the textbox:

```
TheTextBox.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use classes from `System.IO` namespace (e.g. `File`).

```
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("C:\your_file.txt"))
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        string fileContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        myTextBox.Text = fileContent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string value1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\file.txt");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\file.txt","Hello!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{            
   textbox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\your_file.txt"))

        myTextBox.Text = reader.ReadLine();
```